# Angular test for anonymous function assigned to a property

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need to test if an Angular component function (func1) is called by an anonymous function property of an object instantiated dynamically inside of another angular method. A bit tricky to understanding but let me explain that.

I have an exported class that has a property with an anonymous function as type. Something like this:

```
export class Detail {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  onSave: () => void;
}
```

In my component, I have a method that instantiates an object of Detail class and set an anonymous function for `onSave` property that calls `funFn`.

```
myFunction(item: Item){
   const detail = new Detail();
   detail.onSave= (){
     this.runFn(item); 
   }
   this.someService.doSomethingWith(details);
}

runFn(item: Item){
   ... do something cool.
}
```

I want to test if `runFn` is called when `onConfirm` is executed. So, in my test case I have:

```
it("Should calls runFn", function () {
      spyOn(Detail.prototype, 'onSave').and.callThrough();

      const mockItem = new Item();
      component.myFunction(mockItem);

      expect(component.runFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockItem);
});
```

The code above does not work because `onSave` is not a method, is a property. So, How I can mock the instance created inside of `myFunction` and test `runFn` to have been called inside of the anonymous function assigned to `onSave`

Comment: You don't need to spy on onSave. But you need to spy on component.runFn. But even then, since you never do anything with thde detail object created in myFunction, its onSave function can't possibly be called.

Comment: Well, I simplify the code for the demo, but in reality, this code shows a detail popup modal at the end of the function using Detail instance as a parameter and onSave is executed when click on save button of that popup modal.